# I am simply not able to install google analytics in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have been using analytics for some years now but with the recent changes in their UI, I am simply not able to install the tracking code in my wordpress based website even though I follow all procedures. I have put the code from everywhere to everywhere but still the status would not change from "Tracking not installed".
My website is http://thegreatindianroad.in and currently the tracking code is after `<head>`
This is because it hasnt worked just before `</head>` or just before the `</body>` and I read that all other javascripts should come after it.

In the earlier UI, it was extremely easy to "check tracking status" simply by clicking a button but that is no longer the case. Surely I am missing some critical step. Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a plugin? Such as this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

That's what I did and it works fine.

Comment: I just installed, activated and configured the plugin and it still didnt work. :(
Why cant it detect the tracking code I simply dont understand. I have never faced this problem before.

Comment: Is it working now? It might of taken a day for google to collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

I see the tracking code installed on your site and it looks ok as long as you input your correct account number. Maybe wait for a day and then check in GA to see if it's tracking results that way?

Comment: Well here's what is not making sense: It still says "tracking not installed" and yet it is showing me visits by people. Can you make sense of this?